# How to load a controller before connecting to DB or even when MySQL turned off

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I wonder if someone can help me to load a "maintanence" controller before the framwork connects to DB.
that will load tpl file.
For example, when the app is under construction and I want to turn the MySQL database off, but I want to show the people who get my web a page (tpl file that is loaded by controller) "we are under construction" page and all this by loading tpl files and not requiring PHP file.

Comment: Just put a file called index.htm in the web root with what you want to show, job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCart core makes the DB connection before any controller is loaded. So if you plan to turn to maintenance mode, before anything is displayed to the user, the DB connection is already established.

It is practically impossible to separate the DB from the core since it is so tightly coupled.

The only solution would be to create a index.html file as a copy of your maintenance mode html like Paul Feakins replied in comments.

here is a clean html you can use. should work for anyone.

in your root directory create `index.html` and paste this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Maintenance</title>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/image/catalog/cart.png" rel="icon" />
</head>
<body>
<nav id="top">
  <div class="container"><div class="pull-left">
  <form action="/index.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-currency">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">                               <strong>$</strong>        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Currency</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
          <button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="EUR">€ Euro</button>
        </li>
                                <li>
          <button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="GBP">£ Pound Sterling</button>
        </li>
                                <li>
          <button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="USD">$ US Dollar</button>
        </li>
                      </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/index.html" />
  </form>
</div>


    <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="/index.html"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">123456789</span></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="/index.html" title="My Account" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">My Account</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <li><a href="/index.html">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="/index.html">Login</a></li>
                      </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/index.html" id="wishlist-total" title="Wish List (0)"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Wish List (0)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html" title="Shopping Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Shopping Cart</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html" title="Checkout"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Checkout</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="logo">          <h1><a href="/index.html">Your Store</a></h1>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"><div id="search" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </span>
</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total">0 item(s) - $0.00</span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
      <p class="text-center">Your shopping cart is empty!</p>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">Categories</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="/index.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Desktops</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="/index.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Laptops &amp; Notebooks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="/index.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Components</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Tablets</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Software</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Phones &amp; PDAs</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Cameras</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<div id="common-maintenance" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"><h1 style="text-align:center;">We are currently performing some scheduled maintenance. <br/>We will be back as soon as possible. Please check back soon.</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h5>Information</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                   <li><a href="/index.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.html">Delivery Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                  </ul>
      </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h5>Customer Service</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Returns</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Site Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h5>Extras</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="/index.html">Brands</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Gift Certificates</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Affiliate</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Specials</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h5>My Account</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="/index.html">My Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Order History</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Wish List</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Newsletter</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p>Powered By <a href="http://www.opencart.com">OpenCart</a><br /> Your Store &copy; 2019</p>
  </div>
</footer>
<!--
OpenCart is open source software and you are free to remove the powered by OpenCart if you want, but its generally accepted practise to make a small donation.
Please donate via PayPal to donate@opencart.com
//-->
</body></html>
```